# how to convert string into integer in jquery..?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert string into integer using jquery but it throwing `NumberFormatException`. How to fix it?

```
<% int ai= Integer.parseInt(beginningBalance.get(i));%>
```

Comment: what is your string?

Comment: your code doesn't look like JavaScript/Jquery. Is that a Java question?

Comment: `+str` turns `str` into a number

Answer (score 1):

The parseInt() function of JS parses a string and returns an integer.

Ex:

```
var a = parseInt("10");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not of javascript.

```
<% int ai= Integer.parseInt(beginningBalance.get(i));%>
```

it looks like ASP.net
if you want pure javascript or jquery then answer is same as provide above.

```
var a = parseInt("10");
```

so you can change your code in javascript like this:

```
var a = parseInt( '<% beginningBalance.get(i); %>');
```